# Auto complete directory according to included file?

Tags: completion

I have a feature request, but I do not know whether there is any package about this. So, could you please give me some hints for me.

Example:

Suppose we have the directories like this: `/foo/bar1/file1`, `/foo/bar2/file2`, and `/foo/bar/file3`.

What I want is when I type `/foo/*/file1` that will be autocompleted to the appropriate directory, according to the directory the file is in. For example, `/foo/bar1/file1`.

(The `*` I show in pattern `/foo/*/file1` is just some symbol to show I am using this feature, which may not needed.)